# Usar diccionario en combobox

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

trato de hacer que dos comboboxes de tkinter estén conectadas mediante un diccionario. Osea, que la llave en el primer combobox llame el valor en el segundo. El problema es que los valores son números y la terminal me arroja: "TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable"
si alguien puede decirme cómo lo corrijo, gracias.

**Edit:** @DanteS. Modifiqué el código conforme a tus especificaciones, la terminal me arroja ahora un problema de argumentos. Le asigné un valor a la variable de control como indicaste, pero no funciona.

```
ventana=customtkinter.CTk()
ventana.geometry("700x500")


    
#Base de datos
#Nombres
conn= conn=mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",
        user="root",
        password="Baelca1", database="Lista_datos_Baelca")
cursor1=conn.cursor()
cursor1.execute('SELECT DISTINCT (Nombre_conductor) as Nombre from Conductores ')
sacar_nombres=cursor1.fetchall()
conn.commit()
conn.close()

Lista_nombres=[r for r, in sacar_nombres]
#Cedulas
conn= conn=mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",
        user="root",
        password="Baelca1", database="Lista_datos_Baelca")
cursor1=conn.cursor()
cursor1.execute('SELECT DISTINCT (Cedula_conductor) as Cedula from Conductores ')
sacar_cedulas=cursor1.fetchall()
conn.commit()
conn.close()

Lista_cedulas=[r for r, in sacar_cedulas]


diccionario_conductores=dict(zip(Lista_nombres, Lista_cedulas))

#función para llamar el valor de la llave
def update_combo():
        if llave.get():
                caja_cedula.set(diccionario_conductores[llave.get()])
        else:
                pass
#Convertir llaves en lista
llaves=[]
for key in diccionario_conductores:
    llaves.append(key)

llave=customtkinter.StringVar(value="")
llave.trace_add("write", update_combo)
#combobox llaves

caja_nombres=customtkinter.CTkComboBox(ventana, variable=llave, values=list(diccionario_conductores))
caja_nombres.grid()

#combobox valores

caja_cedula=customtkinter.CTkComboBox(ventana)
caja_cedula.grid()

ventana.mainloop()
```

Comment: Recien me entero que editaste la pregunta para agregar información. Las menciones no funcionan en publicaciónes al parecer. La proxima te recomiendo informarme sobre tu edición con un comentario en mi respuesta. Intentaste con lo que propuse en mi comentario en la respuesta que hice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nota: Como no tengo (ni quiero instalarme) mysql, modifiqué el código para que, en lugar de consultar una base de datos, tenga un diccionario hardcodeado:

```
import customtkinter

ventana=customtkinter.CTk()
ventana.geometry("700x500")

dic=dict(zip("ABC", (1, 2, 3)))

#combobox llaves

caja_nombres=customtkinter.CTkComboBox(ventana,  values=list(dic))
caja_nombres.grid()

#combobox valores
#Según la terminal, el problema está en la linea de abajo
caja_cedula=customtkinter.CTkComboBox(ventana,  values=dic[caja_nombres.get()])

ventana.mainloop()
```

---

#### Explicación

Imagina que tenés un diccionario así:

```
{"a":1, "b":2, "c":3}
```

Lo que haces luego de crearlo es en values, obtener del diccionario, de manera inmediata, el valor del diccionario cuya clave es la cadena proporcionada por `caja_nombres.get()`. Como customtkinter siempre establece la primera opción como default, esa será la primera clave del diccionario (si es que usas Python 3.7 o superior, si no será una clave arbitraria). En el caso del ejemplo (y también supongo que en tu caso), esto es un número.

Por el error, sospecho que, como asume que values va a ser una secuencia (lista, tupla, cadena, todo objeto cuyos elementos se acceden por posición), intenta iterar sobre el numero y, por supuesto, no es posible iterar sobre un número. De hecho, acabo de comprobarlo.

#### Solución

Lo que yo hago cuando me encuentro con la necesidad de actualizar el texto de un widget al seleccionarse algo del Combobox, es usar una variable de control (en este caso StringVar) y usar su método `trace_add` para asociar una función al momento de que cambie de valor de dicha variable.
Esta función, que será llamada automaticamente cada vez que la variable cambie, actualizará el valor del segundo combobox.

```
import customtkinter

def update_combo(*args):
    # parece que customtkinter deja la variable vacía en algun
    # punto. Esto podría ser un problema para esta idea si es que es
    # posible que alguna de las opciones puede ser vacía.
    # para evitar errores, solo seteo la variable si esta no está vacía.

    if(var.get()):
        # ten en cuenta que var.get() devolverá una cadena
        # sin importar el tipo de dato ingresado en el combobox
        caja_cedula.set(dic[var.get()])

ventana=customtkinter.CTk()
ventana.geometry("700x500")

dic=dict(zip("ABC", (1, 2, 3)))

var = customtkinter.StringVar()
var.trace_add("write", update_combo)

caja_nombres=customtkinter.CTkComboBox(ventana, variable=var,  values=list(dic))
caja_nombres.grid()

# aqui, para agregar la lista de valores, 
# es necesario convertir cada valor del diccionario en cadena
caja_cedula=customtkinter.CTkComboBox(ventana,  values=[str(value) for value in dic.values()])
caja_cedula.grid()

ventana.mainloop()
```

Comment: Gracias @DanteS. lo modifiqué cómo dijiste pero la terminal me arroja: TypeError: update_combo() takes 0 positional arguments but 3 were given. ¿Debí pasar algún argumento a la variable?

Comment: De nada! Supongo que quitaste el *args. Esa función recive tres argumentos que no son relevantes para la respuesta. el args se encarga de capturar los argumentos en una tupla que no usamos para nada.

Comment: Hola Dante, disculpa que me perdiera, se me dañó la computadora. Volví a poner el args y funciona perfecto. Muchas gracias por el apoyo, ya casi termino el proyecto. Casi me siento obligado a darte un porcentaje con toda la ayuda que me has prestado. @DanteS.

Comment: Me alegro mucho c: Seria un buen gesto, te lo agradeceria, pero sin presion nwn